# Passing array back to javascript

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Good day!
I have a database with user data in it such as: "usernames, passwords, latitudes and longitudes", so what I am trying to do is to select all the data in the username, latitude and longitude columns, put them in an array and echo it in json format to my device.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("myhost", "tablename", "password", "databasename");
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username, latitude, longitude FROM user");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($statement)){
        $response[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code doesn't execute and store result into a variable, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and then quickly edit your question accordingly before it get downvoted and burried.

Comment: You're not [executing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) the query

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error or problem statement. What exactly happens? Where does it go wrong? What error messages and/or unexpected behaviour are you getting? Is the problem in this PHP code, in the client-side code which is receiving it? "Doesn't work" is what the user would say to you...you're a programmer, so you need to give suitable technical information based on the debugging you've undertaken so far. But as Will says above, it's fairly obvious that you never run the query. If you'd debugged this in detail, you would probably have realised it yourself.

Comment: The next issue after that is you have a typo -  mysql_fetch_assoc should be  mysqli_fetch_assoc. Maybe look up an introductory tutorial which shows you how to write a query using mysqli statements and make sure your code follows all the steps. There are lots of examples online and the correct process should not be a mystery to anyone who does a little bit of research.

Comment: Both issues would have been obvious if you threw up some error logging; `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Hope you learn for next time

Comment: I made a typo when writing it the first time, I do execute it, and I have done debugging, the error is in the php file, when i comment out the :while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($statement)){
        $response[] = $row;
    }   Then the php works, but as soon as that is introduced again, it doesn't even return the response to my client

Answer (score 0):

Just fill in the blanks ;)

lets start line by line

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Connect with more OOP's way

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name");
```

Execute your query

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT username, latitude, longitude FROM user");
```

Store mysql result into a variable

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Display your json

```
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Clean up memory

```
$result->free();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Please don't use die to report errors. [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)